# query to decrease price by VAT 20% in all rows

Tags: mysql

I am trying to remove VAT off all rows in a table, each row is inclusive of VAT, here is how I wok out my VAT in PHP:

```
round($price * $this->get_setting(25)/100,2)
```

But I am unsure of how to do this in MYSQL? I came up with the following:

```
UPDATE suppliers_prices SET price = (price / 1.20)
```

The query obviously works but I am unsure if the calculation is correct?

Comment: What does `get_setting(int)` do >

Comment: sorry should of stated that its a string '20'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"UPDATE suppliers_prices SET price = ROUND((price * " . $this->get_setting(25) . " / 100), 2)"
```

if u dont want use your settings then just

```
UPDATE suppliers_prices SET price = ROUND((price / 1.2), 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this link](http://www.startinbusiness.co.uk/flowchart/8flowchart_vat_deduct.htm) your calculation is correct if you are trying to remove 20%.